# Hibernation between two windows?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

I installed two windows 10 in my laptop. Is it possible that storing the first window's state, after I run the second window, then I restore the first window's state?

Now I can put the first window into sleep or hibernation and later restore it. But, this way I cannot run the second window. It will erase all stored state.

Is it possible that I do something like hibernation to the first, then run the second, and then restore the first?

Comment: Are these two Windows licenses different licenses?

Comment: @Superuser If you need to switch Windows fast with minimual hardware, consider put one in VM,

Comment: With two systems in hand, why don't you just try it? Run & Hibernate the first, then boot the second by choose the second in the boot manual? If not working, the only chance is to install the second disk i.e. NVMe drives. Then you can install the 3rd Windows on the NVMe and try run & hibernate 1st then run the 3rd, but this time to get rid of other factors, you'd better only install/enable one of the drive, e.g. install 1st drive->boot 1st OS->hibernate 1st OS->remove/disable 1st drive->install/enable 2st drive->boot 3rd OS->hibernate 3rd OS->switch to 1st drive as above->boot 1st OS.

Comment: If that succeeds, then you can try switching without remove/disable drives, if this still works then goal is achieved. If not, only suboptimal goal - enable/disable drive in BIOS each time you switch can be achieved. Please feedback your experiment results.

Comment: Thank you very much. Maybe that's too complicated for me. It looks like requires some time trying and doing experiments.  I think so far I will suggest to windows and waits if they will add this option. Though, these suggestions are very good ones, technically speaking. Thank you. Also, maybe I will try this to reopen IE tabs. https://www.pcworld.com/article/3131336/how-to-have-windows-re-open-active-windows-and-programs-on-reboot.html